# I am defining post method in link_to but i am getting routing error for get , i have defined a post route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have defined a post route in my routes.rb and using it in `link_to` helper. When I click the link generated by `link_to` helper, I am getting an error that is suppose to be an error for get method.

```
Started GET "/wallpapers/1/like?like=true" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-03 12:51:59 +0530

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/wallpapers/1/like"):

actionpack (5.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:135:in `call_app'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
web-console (3.5.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
sprockets-rails (3.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/quiet_assets.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:602:in `handle_request'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:435:in `process_client'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
puma (3.9.1) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered collection of C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_route.html.erb [11 times] (3.5ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/routes/_table.html.erb (5.0ms)
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.html.erb within rescues/layout (1391.8ms)
```

**my routes.rb file**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do  
  root 'pages#home'
  get '/home', to: 'pages#home'

  resources :wallpapers do
    member do  
      post 'like'
    end
  end
end
```

**my link_to**

```
<%= link_to like_wallpaper_path(@wallpaper), :method => :post  do %>
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i>
<% end %>
```

Comment: and the error is?

Comment: Error is No route matches [GET] "/wallpapers/2/like"

Comment: with the full backtrace, please

Comment: @ArjunSingh Run `rake routes` in you terminal. It shows the list of routes with parameters and type. Check whether the requested routes are available or not.

Comment: Could it be that your browser has JavaScript disabled? Or you're not using the link with a simple left-mouse-button click? link_to's documentation on the :method option is: `Supported verbs are :post, :delete, :patch, and :put. Note that if the user has JavaScript disabled, the request will fall back to using GET.`

Comment: I have ran rake routes it shows the like_wallpaper POST   /wallpapers/:id/like(.:format) wallpapers#like

Comment: Please add full error log.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just `method: :post` write `data: { method: 'post' }`. So your link should look like

```
<%= link_to like_wallpaper_path(@wallpaper), data: { method: 'post' }  do %>
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"></i>
<% end %>
```